# What is the inline syntax for returning a value from an anonymous function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda, delegates, coroutine

I've looked up numerous similar posts on StackOverflow, but they don't seem to come close to my issue as my lambda is within a Coroutine.

My code :

```
public string FetchInternetItems()
    {

      WWW www = new WWW(someURL);

      StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www, callback => {

      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callback))
      {
        Debug.Log("Successfully worked..");
      }
      else
      {
        return "Did not connect to remote server.";
      }

      }));
```

Excerpt from `WaitForRequest` :

```
IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www, Action<string> callback)
    {
        yield return www;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            if (callback != null)
            {
              callback(www.text);
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
        }
    }
```

Coroutine class can be found here : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Which returns the error :

```
Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value
```

Ideally, I would like it to return the `callback`, unless nothing came through, and instead return the `Did not connect to remote server.` message.

Comment: It sounds like the second parameter to `WaitForRequest` is a void delegate, in which case it cannot return a value.  What would you expect it to return he value to?

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense. I expect a `string` value. My apologies for not including that method as well.

Comment: My question is what should _receive_ the return value?  The code is just starting a co-routine, so there's nothing to receive the return.  Also, `Asction<string` takes a string as a parameter and does not return anything.  `Func<string>` would return a `string` but you can't use it in place of an `Action<string>`

Comment: @Trip check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `WaitForRequest`-method has a parameter of type `Action<string>` callback. `Action` is just a delegate for a method returning *nothing* (`void`), thus you can´t call `return ...` in such a delegate. However your design seems to be broken anyway. In case of an error you return a string, if everything runs correct you want to return the `WWW`-instance which seems kind of contradictory, doesn´t it?

You could just throw an exception in case of an error instead of returning a string:

```
IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www, Action<string> callback)
```

Which you can now call like this:

```
StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www, callback => 
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callback))
    {
        Debug.Log("Successfully worked..");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Did not connect to remote server.");
    }
}
```

The idea here is that if you can´t connect to the server there is no way for your application to continue working appropriately, so you can leave with an exception.

Comment: That makes way more sense. I very much would rather throw an exception than a string. I'll try that out

Comment: Ah that makes so much. Thanks so much for that response. If I switch the return to void as you mention, that seems to cause my method `WaitForRequest`  to say `cannot be an iterator block because void is not an iterator interface type` and then my `FetchInternetItems` fails because `cannot convert from void to System.Collections.IEnumerator`

Comment: You should provide the code of `StartCoroutine` also, I suppose it expects an argument of type `Enumerator` for whatever reason.

Comment: Right that Enumerator is definitely an expectation. [coroutine class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Comment: @HimBromBeere StartCoroutine is Unity3D specific, not usual c# stuff. So you are meant to pass a method which returns IEnumerator.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @HimBromBeere !

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your method signature:

```
public string FetchInternetItems()
```

it expects you to return a string.

Instead of returning a string from method scope, you are returning it from an anonymous method.

```
return "Did not connect to remote server.";
```

The above line says that you are trying to return a string from anonymous method which doesn't allow it causing following error:

> Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot
>   return a value

`FetchInternetItems()` would end its execution without waiting for `coroutine` `WaitForRequest` to finish. So both executions are not related to each other. Having said that you won't be able to use response string that you are returning in `FetchInternetItems()`.

To work around this problem, a simple solution is to change the signature to

```
public void FetchInternetItems(Action<string> callBack);
```

This is how you would call this method:

```
FetchInternerItems( result => { Debug.Log("This is response text from www : " + result);});
```

OR like this:

```
FetchInternerItems(OnCompleted);


void OnCompleted(string response)
{
    Debug.Log("This is response text from www: " + response);
    // You can do other stuff here...
}
```

If there is more to know. please ask in comment sections. Hope this helps.